# MVC  c# Create in Controller with 2 tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC .

I am trying to create 2 new records in 2 tables - employee and address table.

I have the following so far:

```
db.employee.AddObject(empmodel.employee);
db.address.AddObject(empmodel.address); 
db.SaveChanges();
```

When an employee record is created, it creates an EmpID record which is autogenerated.
I need to get that EmpID and create a new record in the address table with that EmpID as 
as there is a primary foreign key relationship between the 2 tables.

I am not sure how to get the EmpID from employee table and then create a new record for the address table. I thought I could get it after AddObject but it did not create an employee record.

Comment: You really should (need to) list the technology and language, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try saving changes after adding employee.

```
db.employee.AddObject(empmodel.employee);
db.SaveChanges();    
db.address.AddObject(empmodel.address); 
db.SaveChanges();
```